# Ruby on Rails form method with select_datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime

I have a form in Ruby on Rails that uses methods like f.label, f.textarea

I want to also use the same methods for f.select_datetime, but it doesn't work. How can I get a select_datetime input to work with the normal form methods?

```
        <tr>
          <td><%= f.label :price %>:</td>
          <td>
            <%= f.text_field :price, :placeholder => "price (decimal format, e.g. 12.99 or 19)" %>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><%= f.label :ends_at %>:</td>
          <td>
            <%= select_datetime Time.now + 4.days %>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: can you pleasse show me what the error you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<%= f.datetime_select Time.now + 4.days %>`

Here is the documentation for it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:field_name, :default => { Time.now + 4.days }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

best for datetime select
`<%= f.datetime_select(:offer_end, :default => { :hour => 23, :minute => 59 }) %>`

Refer this link [Datetime select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/datetime_select)